# How did Sinestro get the fear/yellow ring?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

In the MMORPG *DC Universe Online*, it was said Sinestro was expelled from the Green Lantern Corps and as an act of revenge he got the fear/yellow ring and created his own Yellow Lantern Corps to fight the Green Lanterns. But in the movie *Green Lantern* they depicted him as still in the Green Lantern Corps and at the end of the credits, he was

> compelled to try on the fear ring, and thus became corrupted by it.

Is there canon information to how and also why Sinestro got the fear/yellow ring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the [DC Wiki](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Thaal_Sinestro_%28New_Earth%29) and the [Wikipedia entry on Sinestro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestro) have him getting the yellow power ring from the [Weaponers of Qward.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qward)

Sinestro was, depending on continuity, a former Green Lantern or additionally the Green Lantern who trained Hal Jordan.  Sinestro made the people of the planet Korugar worship him like a god.  This led to the Guardians of Oa exiling him to the planet Qward in the anti-matter universe.  The Weaponers of Qward had a long hatred of the Guardians and created the yellow ring for Sinestro because the Green Lantern Corps rings are powerless against the color yellow.

This was all before the various mood ring color wars though and the New 52.  DC may retcon it so Sinestro found the ring in a crackerjack box.